# RMSE variance estimates in repeated K-fold on the test data using caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

I'd like to know if it is possible to estimate the RMSE variance of the model trained in each K-fold on the test data.
I'm using the crantastic caret package. 
For example:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats = 20,
                     allowParallel = TRUE) 
gbmGrid <- expand.grid(interaction.depth = seq(9, 11, by = 1),
                       n.trees = seq(700, 900, by = 25),
                       shrinkage = c(0.01, 0.025, 0.05))
set.seed(100)
gbmFit <- train(R ~ .,
                data = trainSet,
                method = "gbm",
                tuneGrid = gbmGrid,
                verbose = FALSE,
                trControl = ctrl)
```

`gbmFit$resample` gives me the RMSE of each K-fold but I'd like to have the RMSE of the trained model of each K-fold relative to the test data. Is it possible?

To illustrate this further, based on the best model out of train one can predict the values of the output variables for a testset:

```
predict(gbmFit, testSet)
```

However it would be nice to do this for the ixk models (20x5) used in `train` and not only for the best model. For models which are very sensitive to model parameters this is a necessity. Given the two best models out of CV, they can have very different accuracy values for the test set. Perhaps the second best model out of CV is the overall best model. See http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/cv-final.pdf

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. What does "relative to the test data" mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: @topepo Just included additional text that hopefully will make my question clearer. Thanks

Comment: The answer is obviously no. `caret` didn't save intermediate models. But I think it could be possible to modify the source code to add such functionality.